# how to get the part id by the order id and the part has no one else ordered

Tags: sql

Having table has orer_id and part_id fields.  The part could exist in multiple orders, like 123, 456 exist in order 000000000001 and 000000000002

```
| order_id     | part_id | 
=========================|
| 000000000001 | 00123   |  
| 000000000001 | 00456   | 
| 000000000001 | 00789   | 
| 000000000002 | 00123   | 
| 000000000002 | 00456   |
```

want to find out the part_id  ordered by the order_id but the part does not order by anyone else other than the provided order_id.

for example,  query by oerder_id = 000000000001, and want to see the result {789}  (since 123 and 456 are also ordered by other order_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery

```
select * from yourtable a
where order_id = '1'
and part_id not in (select part_id from yourtable where order_id <> a.order_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery, that checks for other orders with the same part.

```
SELECT t1.part_id
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.order_id = '000000000001'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM elbat t2
                                    WHERE t2.order_id <> t1.order_id
                                          AND t2.part_id = t1.part_id);
```

Comment: should the  `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *`    be      `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.order_id`  ?

Comment: @lannyf: That (almost) never makes a difference. With `EXISTS` it only matters if such a record exists or not. The expressions after `SELECT` (almost) never really evaluated (in almost all recent DBMS at least). So, if you think it looks better, you can change it to whatever you think.